Screenshot of the Week #131: Happy Holidays 2024!
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 131st edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! arghtype's screenshot from star-wars-jedi-survivor won with 15 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for (a little less than) a week, until December 23, 2024, then have a week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at December 30, 2024, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Holidays
The end is nigh! Of this year of the Gregorian calendar! Let's celebrate by posting screenshots of merry moments of misadventure, seasonal scenery, holiday hikes, fun with friends or family, a deluge of decoration, or whatever other seasonal content you can muster!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

A friendly reminder to look out for sinkholes this winter.

metro-exodus

I'm not sure but I think there might be a traffic jam going on there

@Clockwork Yes, but this one's caused by gravity, not human error :)

Don’t forget to roll a perception check when opening your presents!

baldurs-gate-3

[rolls a 1] Looks like a normal present to me!

I’m going to be very disappointed if those eyes don’t belong to a bunch of kittens.

"Eyes? I don't see any eyes. It might be a mimic, you say? OR it might have legendary treasure!"

I would Not Open It


fish-wrangler

Party after we beat the endboss. dragon-quest-8


lost-saga


Can't say I miss this game, but I had a lot of fun sharing some good moments with friends.
